# How to code this "strange" sort in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to write a function which performs efficiently this "strange" sort (I am sorry for this pseudocode, it seems to me to be the clearest way to introduce the problem):

```
l=[[A,B,C,...]]
while some list in l is not sorted (increasingly) do
  find a non-sorted list (say A) in l
  find the first two non-sorted elements of A (i.e. A=[...,b,a,...] with b>a)
  l=[[...,a,b,...],[...,b+a,...],B,C,...]
```

Two important things should be mentioned:

1. The sorting is dependent on the choice of the first two
   non-sorted elements: `if A=[...,b,a,r,...], r<a<b` and we choose to
   sort wrt to `(a,r)` then the final result won't be the same. This is
   why we fix the two first non-sorted elements of `A`.
2. Sorting this way always comes to an end.

An example:

```
In: Sort([[4,5,3,10]])
Out: [[3,4,5,10],[5,7,10],[10,12],[22],[4,8,10]]
```

since

```
(a,b)=(5,3): [4,5,3,10]->[[4,3,5,10],[4,8,10]]
(a,b)=(4,3): [[4,3,5,10],[4,8,10]]->[[3,4,5,10],[7,5,10],[4,8,10]]
(a,b)=(7,5): [[3,4,5,10],[7,5,10],[4,8,10]]->[[3,4,5,10],[5,7,10],[12,10],[4,8,10]]
(a,b)=(12,10): [[3,4,5,10],[5,7,10],[12,10],[4,8,10]]->[[3,4,5,10],[5,7,10],[10,12],[22],[4,8,10]]
```

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

Why am I considering this problem:
I am trying to do some computations with the Universal Enveloping Algebra of a Lie algebra. This is a mathematical object generated by products of some generators x_1,...x_n. We have a nice description of a generating set (it amounts to the ordered lists in the question), but when exchanging two generators, we need to take into account the commutator of these two elements (this is the sum of the elements in the question). I haven't given a solution to this question because it would be close to the worst one you can think of. I would like to know how you would implement this in a good way, so that it is pythonic and fast. I am not asking for a complete solution, only some clues. I am willing to solve it by myself .

Comment: In your example, you start by choosing a list `[...., b, a, ...]` and then your new `l` again has this list in it, at the front.  Why would you not immediately repeat, choosing the same list again?  (Or is there some other problem with your example?  Your brackets are unmatched in the `l = ...` line.)

Comment: Is this procedure supposed to do some useful work? What actual problem is it intended to solve?

Comment: @BrenBarn thank you, yes there were two mistakes.

Comment: This looks like homework or a programming challenge. You've described the problem, but haven't shown an attempt to solve it.

Comment: I can see this problem is not of your level just from the way you are approaching it. However, I have solved it for you [here](https://gist.github.com/StamKaly/f6a26b4298e1b653c29a11e7c1c6d70b). But keep in mind stackoverflow is not for **solving** your problems, but rather **helping** you solve them. It doesn't look like you've tried anything at all in your problem. Try solving any problems yourself first and then, only if you **can't**, ask a question **including** what you've tried.

Comment: This is not an exercise, nor a challenge. Please read my edit. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Alright then! Great to hear, I'll post an answer explaining what my code does in a sec. I found a small bug when the last number of the list is smaller than its previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation that could use some improvement:

```
def strange_sort(lists_to_sort):
    # reverse so pop and append can be used
    lists_to_sort = lists_to_sort[::-1]
    sorted_list_of_lists = []
    while lists_to_sort:
        l = lists_to_sort.pop()
        i = 0
        # l[:i] is sorted
        while i < len(l) - 1:
            if l[i] > l[i + 1]:
                # add list with element sum to stack
                lists_to_sort.append(l[:i] + [l[i] + l[i + 1]] + l[i + 2:])
                # reverse elements
                l[i], l[i + 1] = l[i + 1], l[i]
                # go back if necessary
                if i > 0 and l[i - 1] > l [i]:
                    i -= 1
                    continue
            # move on to next index
            i += 1
        # done sorting list
        sorted_list_of_lists.append(l)
    return sorted_list_of_lists

print(strange_sort([[4,5,3,10]]))
```

This keeps track of which lists are left to sort by using a stack. The time complexity is pretty good, but I don't think it's ideal

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you would have to implement a `while` loop which would check if all of the numbers inside of the lists are sorted. I will be using `all` which checks if all the objects inside a sequence are `True`.

```
def a_sorting_function_of_some_sort(list_to_sort):
    while not all([all([number <= numbers_list[numbers_list.index(number) + 1] for number in numbers_list 
                        if not number == numbers_list[-1]]) 
                   for numbers_list in list_to_sort]):

        for numbers_list in list_to_sort:

            # There's nothing to do if the list contains just one number
            if len(numbers_list) > 1:
                for number in numbers_list:
                    number_index = numbers_list.index(number)
                    try:
                        next_number_index = number_index + 1
                        next_number = numbers_list[next_number_index]
                    # If IndexError is raised here, it means we don't have any other numbers to check against,
                    # so we break this numbers iteration to go to the next list iteration
                    except IndexError:
                        break
                    if not number < next_number:
                        numbers_list_index = list_to_sort.index(numbers_list)
                        list_to_sort.insert(numbers_list_index + 1, [*numbers_list[:number_index], number + next_number, 
                                                                     *numbers_list[next_number_index + 1:]])
                        numbers_list[number_index] = next_number
                        numbers_list[next_number_index] = number
                        # We also need to break after parsing unsorted numbers
                        break
    return list_to_sort
```

Comment: Redundant checks to see if something is sorted and to see which items are not sorted. Looping until IndexError seems a bit sloppy. Fails on multiple cases, e.g. [[4,5,3,6]] or [[2,1]]